# Angular Material: In my mat-selection-list, I'm trying to dynamically create mat-list-options with an array of objects but I'm getting an error?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I'm running into a weird issue where I can't seem to populate a Material `mat-selection-list` with `mat-list-option` that are being created with objects instead of an array of strings. I get this error:

`ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Here is my relevant code:

```
@ViewChild("tagsList") tagsList
  public tags: any = [];
  public selectedTags: any = [];

  ngOnInit() {}



     constructor(
        private utilitiesService: UtilitiesService,
        private tagsService: TagsService,
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AccountTagsAssociatorComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data
      ) {
        this.selectedTags = data.tags
        this.tagsService.getAll().then(tags => {
          this.tags = tags.docs;
        })
      }

      selectOption(options) {
        this.selectedTags = this.tagsList.selectedOptions.selected.map(selectedOption => {
          return selectedOption.value
        })
      }
```

In my HTML:

```
<mat-selection-list
    (selectionChange)="selectOption($event)"
     #tags >
    <mat-list-option [value]="tag.id" [selected]="selectedTags && selectedTags.indexOf(tag.id) > -1" *ngFor="let tag of tags; let i = index">
      {{tag.name}}
    </mat-list-option>
  </mat-selection-list>
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Edit: I have updated my code to show a bit more of what's going on. I was having some conflicts, with the `#tags` and the `this.tags` in my component so I changed them. However, this still hasn't solved my problem :/

Comment: What's up with your ```#tags``` template variable? Do you also have a ```tags``` property in the component that's conflicting?

Comment: Maybe show the structure of tags array / objects also?

Answer (score 1):

Use KeyValue pipe to iterate objects:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

You can then access object properties from value, e.g. item.value.prop1